# What is Azure's Microsoft.Insights Resource Provider?

Tags: azure

I am just starting to use Azure and I saw that I wasn't getting any metrics for my storage and other resources because I didn't have the `microsoft.insights` resource provider as part of my subscription. I registered my subscription with `microsoft.insights` and I got all the data I was looking for, but I'm wondering what the implications are of registering with `microsoft.insights`. Do I pay extra money? Is there a formal name where I can learn more about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Azure Resource Manager (ARM) model, clients register their subscription with the resource provider to use the features provided by the resource provider. Microsoft.Insights is the resource provider namespace for Azure Monitor which provides features such as metrics, diagnostic logs, activity logs, autoscale, and metric alerts. For viewing storage metrics, this requires you to enable storage analytics on your storage account which saves the metrics back into the storage account itself. There are no additional charges beyond the storage costs of the storage analytic data.

For more details on Storage Analytics, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-analytics

For more details on Azure Monitor, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/

Answer (score 1):

Azure uses concept of resource providers to represent entities that act on behalf of various resources. Registering a resource provider costs nothing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview#resource-providers

Comment: Does using the resources that microsoft.insights manages cost something? I can't find any information on what resources the microsoft.insights resource provider manages.