# does not have authorization to perform action 'microsoft.insights/logs/read' over scope

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitor

While creating a "Custom log search" alert in Azure Monitor, I'm receiving the following error when the query editor loads:

> Failed to retrieve schema. Please try to refresh the page.
> The client 'blah@msft.com' with object id 'f771d999-7f9e-46dd-9f29-ce11b77aa64e' does not have authorization to perform action 'microsoft.insights/logs/read' over scope '/subscriptions/f8ec86a6-6797-4f4e-bf4f-45881d57a16f/providers/microsoft.insights/logs/metadata' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

What permission(s) need to change? And what resource does 'microsoft.insights' correspond to?

Answer (score 0):

> What permission(s) need to change?

In Access Control (IAM) of the subscription, add the requesting user to the `Log Analytics Reader` role

[image: screenshot of IAM on subscription]

> Role name: Log Analytics Reader
> Role desc: Log Analytics Reader can view and search all monitoring data as well as and view monitoring settings, including viewing the configuration of Azure diagnostics on all Azure resources.

---

> what resource does 'microsoft.insights' correspond to?

Apparently Microsoft.Insights is Azure Monitor ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42824408/185123))